# Makefile - Compile all sub directories and output .o files in a separate directory

Tags: bash, makefile, compilation, rules, subdirectory

I have this command from my bash script

```
find . -type f -name "*.c" -execdir bash -c "f={}; kos-cc $KOS_CFLAGS -c {} -o $PWD/\${f%.c}.o" \;
```

Its job it to recursively search the current directory ($PWD) for .c files, compile them with my "kos-cc" compiler then output all the .o files into the current working directory.

I want to move parts of my bash script into a makefile and this line is the last one that stumps me. I know how to make rules that compiles c files from directory A and outputs the .o files into directory B, but here directory A isn't always the same (Since I need to handle sub directories too). How do I do the equivalent task in a Makefile either with a rule or a command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not trivial because you have your sources in different directories and simple make pattern rules cannot easily handle this. But using [slightly more advanced make features](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Eval-Function) can make it:

```
SRC := $(shell find . -type f -name "*.c")
OBJ := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(notdir $(SRC)))

.PHONY: all    
all: $(OBJ)

define COMPILE_rule
$$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$$(notdir $(1))): $(1)
    kos-cc $$(KOS_CFLAGS) -c -o $$@ $$<
endef
$(foreach s,$(SRC),$(eval $(call COMPILE_rule,$(s))))

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJ)
```

Beware: you could have several source files with the same base name in different directories. And if this happens, you will end up with a fatal conflict of object file names...

**EDIT** (add conflicts detection):

The following detects conflicts situations and issues an error (replace `error` by `warning` or `info` depending on the severity level you assign to these conflicts):

```
SRC := $(shell find . -type f -name "*.c")
OBJ := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(notdir $(SRC)))

ifneq ($(words $(OBJ)),$(words $(sort $(OBJ))))
$(error object file name conflicts detected)
endif
```

(`sort` sorts and also removes duplicates and `words` returns the number of space-separated words in its string parameter).

Comment: I think there's a few issues with the brackets. The OBJ definition should have an extra right bracket at the end and after that when I run make it says "unterminated call to function 'patsubst': missing ')'." but I don't know exactly where the right bracket goes on that one. Edit: Its before the colon and it works, thanks :)

Comment: Also I didn't consider the same-named file situation. This will be used by other people later on so I'll need to think about that. For now its not an issue though.

Comment: Sorry for the missing parentheses, I did not test. They should be fixed in the edited answer.  And about the name conflicts, there is a way to detect them and issue a warning or an error. But this is a different problem.

Comment: I finally found some time to add the conflicts detection mechanism (see the edited answer).

Comment: Thanks, thats perfect